# Spring Security Rest DigestEntryPoint's key and realm

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm following baeldung's Spring Security for REST guide, and [he has you create](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/11/20/basic-and-digest-authentication-for-a-restful-service-with-spring-security-3-1/) a `DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

When you do that, he says you should set the RealmName and Key in that, and he gives you some values to put in those. In my project I've done that in my Spring Java Configuration like so:

```
DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
entryPoint.setRealmName("Contacts Realm via Digest Authentication");
entryPoint.setKey("acegi");
```

What are those two values though? There aren't any java docs and a google search didn't help me out much.

Should I modify those to values applicable for my specific project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section 9.2 of:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html

But to answer your question, yes.  You should certainly modify the key (as it is ostensibly secret).  The realm is up to you.  Do you plan on having multiple realms within your application?  If not, it doesn't really matter.